# Cannot create a relation between two tables with three primary keys

Tags: sql-server

I recently used *Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle* to convert an Oracle database to a SQL Server database through a two-pass approach.

There is are two tables, `BILL_INFO` and `BILL_INFO_DETAIL`, that are supposed to have a master-detail relation through composite PK. However, when I try to create that relation, I get this error:

> 'BILL_INFO' table saved successfully 'BILL_INFO_DETAIL' table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'FK_BILL_INFO_DETAIL_BILL_INFO'.   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_BILL_INFO_DETAIL_BILL_INFO".  The conflict occurred in database
>   "MyDatabase", table "dbo.BILL_INFO".

The database is plagued with bad data. So I did a basic search in the detail table to find `BILL_NUMBER`, `PAY_MODE_ID`, and `CASHIER_ID` that may not exist in master (one by one) and found two records when searching on `BILL_NUMBER`. I fixed them and also verified that `PAY_MODE_ID` and `CASHIER_ID` were in order.

Still, I cannot create the relation. Same error. Now I wonder if the Tuple is invalid between tables. How do I find a composite key that exists only in details table?

[image]

Comment: `Select * from Bill_Info_Detail d left join Bill_Info on <your three columns> where Bill_Info.column is null`

Comment: In addition to your problem here I wonder if you are applying a UNIQUE key to Bill_Info_Detail when you do not really have to make the key UNIQUE.  Three may be no LineNumber  or TransactionID that would make it unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for non-existing values using:

```
SELECT bill_number, pay_mode_id, cashier_id
FROM Bill_Info_Detail
EXCEPT
SELECT bill_number, pay_mode_id, cashier_id
FROM Bill_Info;
-- and then fix missing data
```

When using composite key, you need to check all columns as tuple.