# Using Where predicate to filter detail.List with another list

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, c#-7.1

I'm trying to get a set of Master-Detail records on the basis of a list of strings that I need to match with each detail's reference number column for each master. So, for example, I have this as a list of strings:

```
string[] listToFilterFor = new [] { "2729113", "2732623", "2734483", "2735355", "2752260" };
```

Anf the DAL function to filter:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<BILL_INFO>> GetBills(IDictionary<string, object> filterCriteria, string operationGuid)
{
    var callerInfo = Shared.CommonAcross.Helper.GetCaller();
    Logger.Info($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Started");

    try
    {
        IList<BILL_INFO> intermResult;

        using (var context = new FinanceConnection())
        {
            var result = context.BILL_INFOS
                                .Include(i => i.MASTER_ACCOUNT)
                                .Include(i => i.MASTER_PAY_MODE)
                                .Include(i => i.MASTER_BANK)
                                .Include(i => i.MASTER_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE)
                                .Include(i => i.MASTER_EDIRHAM_CARD_TYPE);

            if (filterCriteria != null && filterCriteria.Any())
            {
                #region Keys

                var billNumberKey = "BillNumber";
                var cashierNumberKey = "AssignedCashiers";
                var payModeIdKey = "PayModeId";
                var depositIdKey = "DepositId";
                var dateFromKey = "DateFrom";
                var dateToKey = "DateTo";
                var accountsKey = "Account";
                var accountGroupsKey = "AccountGroups";
                var referenceNumber = "ReferenceNumber";
                var referenceNumbers = "ReferenceNumbers";

                #endregion

                if (filterCriteria.ContainsKey(billNumberKey) && filterCriteria.TryGetValue(billNumberKey, out var actualFilterBillNumber))
                    result = result.Where(where => where.BILL_NUMBER.Contains(actualFilterBillNumber.ToString()));

                if (filterCriteria.ContainsKey(referenceNumbers) && filterCriteria.TryGetValue(referenceNumbers, out var actualReferenceNumbers))
                {
                    result = result.Include(i => i.BILL_INFO_DETAIL);
                    result = result.Where(where => where.BILL_INFO_DETAIL.Any(p=>p.));
                }

                #region From/To Dates

                DateTime? tempDateFrom = null;
                DateTime? tempDateTo = null;

                if (filterCriteria.ContainsKey(dateFromKey) && filterCriteria.TryGetValue(dateFromKey, out var actualDateFrom))
                {
                    tempDateFrom = ((DateTime?)actualDateFrom)?.Date;
                }

                if (filterCriteria.ContainsKey(dateToKey) && filterCriteria.TryGetValue(dateToKey, out var actualDateTo))
                {
                    tempDateTo = ((DateTime?)actualDateTo)?.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
                }

                if (tempDateFrom.HasValue && tempDateTo.HasValue)
                {
                    result = result.Where(where => where.BILL_DATE != null && where.BILL_DATE >= tempDateFrom && where.BILL_DATE <= tempDateTo);
                }
                else if (tempDateFrom.HasValue && !tempDateTo.HasValue)
                {
                    result = result.Where(where => where.BILL_DATE != null && where.BILL_DATE >= tempDateFrom && where.BILL_DATE <= tempDateFrom);
                }
                else if (!tempDateFrom.HasValue && tempDateTo.HasValue)
                {
                    result = result.Where(where => where.BILL_DATE != null && where.BILL_DATE >= tempDateTo.Value.Date && where.BILL_DATE <= tempDateTo);
                }

                #endregion
            }

            intermResult = await result.OrderByDescending(o => o.BILL_DATE).Take(10000).ToListAsync();
        }

        Logger.Info($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Returning");
        return intermResult.AsQueryable();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Logger.Error($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Exception [{exp.Message}]", exp);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Task:

I need to go through the master records (`BILL_INFOS`) and look into each master's detail records (`BILL_INFO_DETAILS`) and try to match *AnyOf* listToFilterFor against BILL_INFO_DETAIL.REFERENCE_NUMBER

Comment: You have to get BillInfos, whose details match any of listToFilterFor, orget specific details which were matching??

Comment: @Kacper Master record (BillInfos with details that satisfy the cruteria)

Comment: Can you show, What does Bill_Info entity look like? Is Bill_Info_Details another entity?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correct, i apologize if i have not. Could you use an includes statement.

BILL_INFO.where(x => listToFilterFor.Includes(x.BILL_INFO_DETAILS.REFERENCE_NUMBER)

Comment: The `string[] listToFilterFor` does not have an `.Include()` method

Comment: you will need to .toList() the array first

Comment: Did that but the x.BILL_INFO_DETAILS is a collection and I cannot access the property REFERENCE_NUMBER that way

Comment: sorry, i was thinking of javascript it's actually .contains()

Comment: Can you use the selectMany operator?

Answer (score 0):

I finally sorted this one out as here were composite primary keys involved and a proper tuple was not possible. I found the solution through this question: [Cannot create a relation between two tables with three primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50201776/481656)

I was able to extract a subset.